# how to specific query parameter value in aws application load balancer access logs and cloudfront access logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elb, amazon-cloudfront

I have configured aws cloudfront access logs and aws application load balancer access logs. Now they logs every query string. But I have password value in the query string as well and that value I would like to mask or hide. Is it possible in aws application load balancer access logs or cloudfront logs

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront and ALB do not provide a way to suppress this logging... but sensitive data does not belong in the query string.

See, for example, the OWASP article on [Information Exposure through Query Strings in URL](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url) for further information on this vulnerabity and [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29598/32112) on Information Security Stack Exchange.